# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. in react. Actually the array has a key

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why this error happen.
The "projects" have a key each.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `ProjectList`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Link (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:98148:31)
    at ProjectList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2233:3)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Dashboard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:754:1)
    at FirestoreConnect(Dashboard) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93335:11)
    at Connect(FirestoreConnect(Dashboard)) (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:96289:28)
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:98747:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:98949:29)
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:98382:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:98002:35)
    at App
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:96124:26)


call from https://github.com/iamshaunjp/React-Redux-Firebase-App/blob/lesson-39/marioplan/src/components/dashboard/Dashboard.js
```

The code

```
const ProjectList = ({projects}) => {
    return (
        <div className="project-list section">
            {projects && projects.map(project => {
              return (
                <Link to ={'/project/' + project.id}>
                <ProjectSummary project = {project} key = {project.id} />
                </Link>
              )
            })}
        </div>
              )}

export default ProjectList;
```

```
console.log("ProjectsSample" + JSON.stringify(projects));
```

```
ProjectsSample {"70Vy1qTygmot82hLTXqM":{"createdAt":{"seconds":1614322423,"nanoseconds":379000000},"content":"EE　JUMP","title":"おっとっと冬だぜ","authorUserName":"Zeke","authorId":"kvxg96HGuzL2vtoDS9G8FZSa8E53","answers":{"RFv6bJMG2dmiBqWNZX8O":{"content":"これが・・"}}},"9A2cvtlOoaNHnJ9uxBCi":{"createdAt":{"seconds":1614678213,"nanoseconds":459000000},"authorId":"qzTZftjdF3NIr7TZ3kiC9hbgDym1","title":"tsukuda","authorUserName":"tsukuda","content":"desu."},"DqsnHsTEEY9ztExWuuCQ":{"authorId":12345,"title":"Tite","content":"arataihen","authorLastName":"Ninja","authorFirstName":"Net","createAt":{"seconds":1613974658,"nanoseconds":763000000}}}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the rendered output where your list items each have a unique key?

Comment: You need to add the attribute ```key``` to the immediate child **i.e** ```<Link to ={'/project/' + project.id}  key = {project.id}>```

Answer (score 2):

Giive a shot to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).
As explained in the docs Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. The important highlight on this regard is that Keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. However they don’t need to be globally unique.

This said, when this happens you usually need to move the 'key' property up in the hierarchy if you are mapping sibling components as Mr Mairaj suggested in the comments.

```
const ProjectList = ({projects}) => {
    return (
        <div className="project-list section">
            {projects && projects.map(project => {
              return (
                <Link to ={'/project/' + project.id} key = {project.id} > //moved to parent here
                <ProjectSummary project = {project} />
                </Link>
              )
            })}
        </div>
              )}

export default ProjectList;
```